# Parring data in excel

Tags: excel

I'm not sure i got that right, but it's like this

I got a iframe code to insert in my website, and each iframe code consist a unique product number from Amazon (ASIN), the rest doesn't change.

Each how do I insert thousand of ASIN into that iframe to generate thousand of matching result ?

The iframe code looks like this

```
    <iframe src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=myID-20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&asins=B0080CO2F4&nou=1&ref=tf_til&fc1=F50A0A&IS2=1&lt1=_blank&m=amazon&lc1=1D1DDB&bc1=000000&bg1=FFFFFF&f=ifr" style="width:120px;height:240px;" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The B0080CO2F4 is the ASIN code that link to a unique product, and I got hundred thousand of them.

I think it can be done in excel, but i'm not sure how to.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Provide some sample data. Your question is too vague.

Comment: I just edit, please see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a data setup like this:

[image: tigeravatar example]

It's hard to see, but you can take your basic line and replace the ASIN number with a generic placeholder, I used `[ASIN]`:

```
<iframe src="http://rcm-na.amazon-adsystem.com/e/cm?t=myID-20&o=1&p=8&l=as1&asins=[ASIN]&nou=1&ref=tf_til&fc1=F50A0A&IS2=1&lt1=_blank&m=amazon&lc1=1D1DDB&bc1=000000&bg1=FFFFFF&f=ifr" style="width:120px;height:240px;" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Then, in column A starting in A4 and down is your list of ASIN numbers.
In cell B4 and copied down is this formula:

```
=SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"[ASIN]",A4)
```

And it will replace that generic placeholder with the correct ASIN.  Afterwards you can copy/paste values, or just copy column B into a text file or something.